# Is there a programmable method to transfer files from an iPad to PC? (USB connection)

Tags: python, ios, ipad, usb

I'm currently looking for an automatic method (preferably Pythonic) to transfer a JS generated csv file from an iPad to a PC. Basically, once the PC detects that the iPad device has connected it will execute a script to fetch the csv file and transfer it to the PC for further processing.

I've teased the idea of using the iTune's API to grab the file from the "File Sharing" portion. Although, I admit, I'm not even sure if that is a realistic approach.

I also wonder if there is a socket or serial solution to this, and if that is worth pursuing?